# Is it OK to shutdown socket after write all data to it?

Tags: sockets, server, tcp

I'm writing simple http server.
I want to `shutdown` socket after server send all data.
I considered that compare return byte of `write()` to socket with actuall content length, but I had read that the return value just means that data moved to send-buffer of the socket. (Im not sure and I don't know how can I check it)

If so, can I shutdown the socket just after check the bytes are same? What if the datas sended need to be retransmitted at TCP level after server send `FIN` flag?

Comment: FIN flag is to close a connection, guess u have to open a new connection for retransmission

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OS **does not** discard data you have written when you call shutdown(SHUT_WR). If the other end already shut down its end (you can tell because you received 0 bytes) then you should be able to close the socket, and the OS will keep it open until it has finished sending everything.

The FIN is treated like part of the data. It has to be retransmitted if the other end doesn't receive it, and it doesn't get processed until everything before it has been received. This is called "graceful shutdown" or "graceful close". This is unlike RST, which signals that the connection should be aborted immediately.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So, `shutdown(SHUT_WR)`  does not discard data written, but `close()` does and send RST?

Comment: @mishy I *think* the RST is sent when data is received at a closed socket. Normally one side will shutdown(SHUT_WR) first which tells the other side that no more data will be received, and it can close its socket.